# Update Count on Date wise in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a strange requirement. Here it is. I have a table.

```
DateTime               PhoneNo     Network
-------------------    --------    ---------
11/01/2014 13:05:45    99999999    NetTwo
11/01/2014 13:05:45    99999999    NetOne
11/01/2014 13:05:45    99999999    NetOne
12/01/2014 13:05:45    99999999    NetOne
12/01/2014 13:06:45    99999999    NetOne
12/01/2014 13:07:45    88888888    NetTwo
12/01/2014 13:08:45    77777777    NetThree
```

I have to Update another table by running a stored procedure daily once such that it calculates summary of number of times a caller called a day and it should update it to the corresponding column

DestinationTable:

```
Date        Month year    Phone     Network    01 02 03 -------11-12---30-31
11/01/2014  JAN   2014    99999999  NetOne     0   0  0        2  0    0  0
11/01/2014  JAN   2014    99999999  NetTwo     0   0  0        1  0    0  0
12/01/2014  JAN   2014    99999999  NetTwo     0   0  0        0  2    0  0
12/01/2014  JAN   2014    88888888  NetTwo     0   0  0        0  1    0  0
12/01/2014  JAN   2014    77777777  NetTwo     0   0  0        0  1    0  0
```

Here 01 to 31 are separate columns. I apologize if i didn't explain it properly.

Any Suggestions or approach how to implement this..Thanks for your patience to look into my problem guys. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you soo much for your efforts. Thanks haki and Thinkjet. @think: I learned merge from you :D..

I got my expected result using subqueries inside the result set of with clause.

```
WITH MainFilter(CLI,DAYS,COUNTS)
AS (SELECT TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY.CLI,
TO_CHAR(TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY.CALLSTARTTIME, 'DD'),COUNT(TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY.CLI)
FROM TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY 
WHERE  UPPER(TO_CHAR(TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY.CALLSTARTTIME, 'mon')) =UPPER(i_Month) AND
(SELECTED_DNIS IS NULL OR TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY.DNIS = SELECTED_DNIS) 
GROUP BY TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY.CLI,
TO_CHAR(TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY.CALLSTARTTIME,'DD'))
SELECT MF.CLI,
NVL((SELECT COUNTS FROM MainFilter WHERE MainFilter.DAYS = '01' AND CLI  = MF.CLI ),0)     AS  Day_01,
NVL((SELECT COUNTS FROM MainFilter WHERE MainFilter.DAYS = '02' AND CLI  = MF.CLI ),0) AS  Day_02,
NVL((SELECT COUNTS FROM MainFilter WHERE MainFilter.DAYS = '03' AND CLI  = MF.CLI ),0) AS  Day_03,
--------------------
--------------------
FROM MainFilter MF GROUP BY MF.CLI ;
```

I am worried about the query performance. Is it good to go with this approach ??

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange - it's called a pivot table

this is one way to go

```
select  trunc(DateTime) as date , to_char(datetimem,'MON') as month , to_number(to_char(datetime,'yyyy')) as year , PhoneNo, network , 
    sum(case when to_char(DateTime,'hh24') = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as h00, 
    sum(case when to_char(DateTime,'hh24') = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as h01, 
    .. 
    sum(case when to_char(DateTime,'hh24') = 23 then 1 else 0 end) as h23
from    calls_tables
group by trunc(DateTime) , to_char(datetimem,'MON'), to_number(to_char(datetime,'yyyy')) , PhoneNo, network
```

11g has a pivot function as well.

You should run a search for it.

Comment: Since he has 0-31, I assume it's day-of-month, not hour-of-day.  Also, you're likely to get better performance out of the query by using a Calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

For periodical updates better to use [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement.

First of all, initial setup for code examples below:

```
create table SourceTable(
  DateTime date,
  PhoneNo  varchar2(40),
  Network  varchar2(20)
);

create table DestinationTable(
  CallDate  date,      
  CallMonth varchar2(20),
  CallYear  number,  
  Phone     varchar2(40),
  Network   varchar2(20), 
  d01       number,
  d02       number,
  d03       number,
  d04       number,
  d05       number,
  d06       number,
  d07       number,
  d08       number,
  d09       number,
  d10       number,
  d11       number,
  d12       number,
  d13       number,
  d14       number,
  d15       number,
  d16       number,
  d17       number,
  d18       number,
  d19       number,
  d20       number,
  d21       number,
  d22       number,
  d23       number,
  d24       number,
  d25       number,
  d26       number,
  d27       number,
  d28       number,
  d29       number,
  d30       number,
  d31       number
);
```

Field names are changed to meet standard naming rules.

Schema setup and code available in [**<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f870/1).

Next, query to demonstrate extraction of date and time parts from source table to work with destination:

```
select
  trunc(call_log.DateTime)                                      CallDate,
  to_char(call_log.DateTime,'MON','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  CallMonth,
  extract(year from call_log.DateTime)                          CallYear,
  extract(day from call_log.DateTime)                           CallDay,
  PhoneNo                                                       Phone,
  Network                                                       Network
from 
  SourceTable call_log
order by 
  datetime, phoneno, network
```

Based on date, network and phone number it's possible to group data from source table and make source data for merge:

```
select 
  CallDate, 
  to_char(CallDate,'MON','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  CallMonth,
  extract(year from CallDate)                          CallYear,
  d01, d02, d03, d04, d05, d06, d07, d08, d09, d10,
  d11, d12, d13, d14, d15, d16, d17, d18, d19, d20,
  d21, d22, d23, d24, d25, d26, d27, d28, d29, d30, d31 
from (
  select 
    CallDate, 
    Phone, 
    Network,
    sum(decode(callDay, 1,1,0)) d01,
    sum(decode(callDay, 2,1,0)) d02,
    sum(decode(callDay, 3,1,0)) d03,
    sum(decode(callDay, 4,1,0)) d04,
    sum(decode(callDay, 5,1,0)) d05,
    sum(decode(callDay, 6,1,0)) d06,
    sum(decode(callDay, 7,1,0)) d07,
    sum(decode(callDay, 8,1,0)) d08,
    sum(decode(callDay, 9,1,0)) d09,
    sum(decode(callDay,10,1,0)) d10,
    sum(decode(callDay,11,1,0)) d11,
    sum(decode(callDay,12,1,0)) d12,
    sum(decode(callDay,13,1,0)) d13,
    sum(decode(callDay,14,1,0)) d14,
    sum(decode(callDay,15,1,0)) d15,
    sum(decode(callDay,16,1,0)) d16,
    sum(decode(callDay,17,1,0)) d17,
    sum(decode(callDay,18,1,0)) d18,
    sum(decode(callDay,19,1,0)) d19,
    sum(decode(callDay,20,1,0)) d20,
    sum(decode(callDay,21,1,0)) d21,
    sum(decode(callDay,22,1,0)) d22,
    sum(decode(callDay,23,1,0)) d23,
    sum(decode(callDay,24,1,0)) d24,
    sum(decode(callDay,25,1,0)) d25,
    sum(decode(callDay,26,1,0)) d26,
    sum(decode(callDay,27,1,0)) d27,
    sum(decode(callDay,28,1,0)) d28,
    sum(decode(callDay,29,1,0)) d29,
    sum(decode(callDay,30,1,0)) d30,
    sum(decode(callDay,31,1,0)) d31
  from (
    select
      trunc(call_log.DateTime)            CallDate,
      extract(day from call_log.DateTime) CallDay,
      PhoneNo                             Phone,
      Network                             Network
    from 
      SourceTable call_log
  )
  group by 
    CallDate, Phone, Network
)  
order by 
  CallDate, Phone, Network
```

And last step is merging of prepared data into destination table:

```
merge into DestinationTable call_totals
using (
  select       -- Previous select (removed unneeded columns and ordering)
    CallDate, 
    Phone, 
    Network,
    sum(decode(callDay, 1,1,0)) d01,
    sum(decode(callDay, 2,1,0)) d02,
    sum(decode(callDay, 3,1,0)) d03,
    sum(decode(callDay, 4,1,0)) d04,
    sum(decode(callDay, 5,1,0)) d05,
    sum(decode(callDay, 6,1,0)) d06,
    sum(decode(callDay, 7,1,0)) d07,
    sum(decode(callDay, 8,1,0)) d08,
    sum(decode(callDay, 9,1,0)) d09,
    sum(decode(callDay,10,1,0)) d10,
    sum(decode(callDay,11,1,0)) d11,
    sum(decode(callDay,12,1,0)) d12,
    sum(decode(callDay,13,1,0)) d13,
    sum(decode(callDay,14,1,0)) d14,
    sum(decode(callDay,15,1,0)) d15,
    sum(decode(callDay,16,1,0)) d16,
    sum(decode(callDay,17,1,0)) d17,
    sum(decode(callDay,18,1,0)) d18,
    sum(decode(callDay,19,1,0)) d19,
    sum(decode(callDay,20,1,0)) d20,
    sum(decode(callDay,21,1,0)) d21,
    sum(decode(callDay,22,1,0)) d22,
    sum(decode(callDay,23,1,0)) d23,
    sum(decode(callDay,24,1,0)) d24,
    sum(decode(callDay,25,1,0)) d25,
    sum(decode(callDay,26,1,0)) d26,
    sum(decode(callDay,27,1,0)) d27,
    sum(decode(callDay,28,1,0)) d28,
    sum(decode(callDay,29,1,0)) d29,
    sum(decode(callDay,30,1,0)) d30,
    sum(decode(callDay,31,1,0)) d31
  from (
    select
      trunc(call_log.DateTime)            CallDate,
      extract(day from call_log.DateTime) CallDay,
      PhoneNo                             Phone,
      Network                             Network
    from 
      SourceTable call_log
  )
  group by 
    CallDate, Phone, Network
) existing_calls
on (                
  -- Link prepared data from source table to destination
  call_totals.CallDate = existing_calls.CallDate
  and
  call_totals.Phone = existing_calls.Phone
  and
  call_totals.Network = existing_calls.Network
)
when matched then
  -- If record for date, phone and record found - update statistics
  update
    set
      d01 = existing_calls.d01,
      d02 = existing_calls.d02,
      d03 = existing_calls.d03,
      d04 = existing_calls.d04,
      d05 = existing_calls.d05,
      d06 = existing_calls.d06,
      d07 = existing_calls.d07,
      d08 = existing_calls.d08,
      d09 = existing_calls.d09,
      d10 = existing_calls.d10,
      d11 = existing_calls.d11,
      d12 = existing_calls.d12,
      d13 = existing_calls.d13,
      d14 = existing_calls.d14,
      d15 = existing_calls.d15,
      d16 = existing_calls.d16,
      d17 = existing_calls.d17,
      d18 = existing_calls.d18,
      d19 = existing_calls.d19,
      d20 = existing_calls.d20,
      d21 = existing_calls.d21,
      d22 = existing_calls.d22,
      d23 = existing_calls.d23,
      d24 = existing_calls.d24,
      d25 = existing_calls.d25,
      d26 = existing_calls.d26,
      d27 = existing_calls.d27,
      d28 = existing_calls.d28,
      d29 = existing_calls.d29,
      d30 = existing_calls.d30,
      d31 = existing_calls.d31
when not matched then 
  -- If record for date, phone and record not found - add new one
  insert (
    CallDate, CallMonth, CallYear, Phone, Network,
    d01, d02, d03, d04, d05, d06, d07, d08, d09, d10,
    d11, d12, d13, d14, d15, d16, d17, d18, d19, d20,
    d21, d22, d23, d24, d25, d26, d27, d28, d29, d30, d31 
  ) values (
    existing_calls.CallDate,
    to_char(existing_calls.CallDate, 'MON', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
    extract( year from existing_calls.CallDate),
    existing_calls.Phone,
    existing_calls.Network,
    existing_calls.d01, 
    existing_calls.d02, 
    existing_calls.d03, 
    existing_calls.d04, 
    existing_calls.d05, 
    existing_calls.d06, 
    existing_calls.d07, 
    existing_calls.d08, 
    existing_calls.d09, 
    existing_calls.d10,
    existing_calls.d11, 
    existing_calls.d12, 
    existing_calls.d13, 
    existing_calls.d14, 
    existing_calls.d15, 
    existing_calls.d16, 
    existing_calls.d17, 
    existing_calls.d18, 
    existing_calls.d19, 
    existing_calls.d20,
    existing_calls.d21, 
    existing_calls.d22, 
    existing_calls.d23, 
    existing_calls.d24, 
    existing_calls.d25, 
    existing_calls.d26, 
    existing_calls.d27, 
    existing_calls.d28, 
    existing_calls.d29, 
    existing_calls.d30, 
    existing_calls.d31 
  )
;
```